# Where to use Entities and ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In an MVC application where should the database entities be restricted to.  They should obviously be used in the data layer, but should they be used/returned in the business/service layer too?  What about ViewModels?  Where should their use be restricted to?  Are there any other models that should have their scope restricted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, it depends on the scope of your application. You can return the entities to the business layer if you have a simple usage, say you are using all the properties of the entity class in the view.

Suppose, if you have a complex model where you want a combination of different entities that you are going to use in the view, then you use view models. In the latter case you save all the data into view model in data-access layer and return the view model to business layer or you can get the models into business layer and save them into view model at this level and return to the controller action method. But the controller action method should finally get the view model.